# Java foxtrot Worker produce deadlock when use with invokeLater

Tags: java, swing

We are using foxtrot package for stop freeze the swing application.

But in this below code it make a deadlock.

```
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

import foxtrot.Task;
import foxtrot.Worker;

public class FoxtrotExample extends JFrame {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    FoxtrotExample example = new FoxtrotExample();
    example.setVisible(true);
}

boolean st = true;

public FoxtrotExample() {
    super("Foxtrot Example");

    final JButton button = new JButton("Take a nap !");
    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.out.println("Start..");
            button.setText("Sleeping...");

            String text = null;
            try {
                text = (String) Worker.post(new Task() {
                    public Object run() throws Exception {
                        System.out.println("Inside Worker 1");
                        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                try {
                                    System.out.println("Inside invokeLater");
                                    Worker.post(new Task() {

                                        @Override
                                        public Object run()
                                                throws Exception {
                                            System.out.println("Inside Worker 2");
                                            st = false;
                                            return null;
                                        }
                                    });
                                } catch (Exception e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }
                        });


                        while (st) {
                            System.out.println("Inside the loop..");
                            try {
                                Thread.sleep(1000);
                            } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                                e1.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                        return "Slept !";
                    }
                });
            } catch (Exception x) {
            }
            button.setText(text);
            System.out.println("Finished.....");
        }
    });

    setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

    Container c = getContentPane();
    c.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    c.add(button);

    setSize(300, 200);

    Dimension screen = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
    Dimension size = getSize();
    int x = (screen.width - size.width) >> 1;
    int y = (screen.height - size.height) >> 1;
    setLocation(x, y);
 }
}
```

If use ConcurrentWorker this will work fine.Can any one explane this.
I am bit confuse how EDT behave here ?

Comment: I wouldn't have thought that `invokeLater` would be able to execute the request until the `Worker` has completed, but that assumes that it's been executed on the original dispatcher and not the foxtrot dispatcher.  You do understand what foxtrot does don't you?

Comment: In fact, I think your "deadlock" is caused by your `while-loop`, as nothing is getting around to getting dispatched or processed by either the original EDT or foxtrot

Comment: I know about foxtrot.But why second worker not work ?.

Comment: `Worker` seems to be singlton, from which all events are dispatched through it's "dispatcher", so while worker 1 is blocking the dispatcher, nothing can be processed, so worker 2 can't be executed or processed ... AFAIK. I'm glad you "know about foxtrot", but do you understand what it does and how it works?

Comment: So, quick test, if you remove the `while-loop`, the second task will be allowed to execute.  This seems to suggest that the task is posted into the original dispatcher, but while the first task is running, that dispatcher isn't processing new events (the first worker is control that)

Comment: So, as I understand the workers, Task #1 calls `invokeLater` and then BLOCKS the current dispatcher.  The `invokeLater` request is enqued in the event queue, but because Task #1 is blocking the dispatcher, the request can not be processed, UNTIL, Task #1 exits.  Essentially, you have a "block event dispatching thread" problem, just wrapped in an extra layer or two.  The `Worker` is processing the Event Queue over the original dispatcher, which is what foxtrot is designed to do.  It allows you to stop the code execution at the point you `post` your `Task`,

Comment: but allows the `Worker` to continue processing events off the event queue, so as not to block the UI.  So all the "normal" "don't block the event dispatching thread" rules still apply.  The tasks are not run concurrently

Comment: I think Worker is single Thread.If one worker is block other cannot work till it finish.Use the **Concurrent Worker** is the solution.Is that right ?.

Comment: You have to remember, foxtrots purpose is to act like a event dispatcher thread, so, as I said, all the rules of working with the EDT remain the same. I don't know if foxtrot can be multithreaded

Comment: From the documentation *"Foxtrot's ConcurrentWorker is a synchronous solution like Worker. Where Worker enqueues the Tasks or Jobs to be run in a single worker queue, so that they're executed one after the other, in ConcurrentWorker the Tasks or Jobs are run as soon as they are posted and each in its own worker thread."* - So, I'd say you'd have to give it a test and see

Comment: Thank you very much MadProgrammer

Answer (score 0):

This is the result of my program.

```
Start 1st worker
In the loop
Start invoke later
In the loop
In the loop
In the loop
In the loop
......
```

It start the 1st worker.Then part of the code is in invokeLater.So request is enqued in the event queue and start the loop.Later execute the invokeLater but not execute the 2nd worker because first worker still doing some work.Since worker are ruining one after another and it runs on a single worker queue 2nd worker cannot execute and deadlock comes.

Thanks to MadProgrammer i understood this.Hope this is correct.